# How do I solve Appium-desktop could not find my adb

Tags: appium

I was trying to set a win10 Appium environment to do some Android automation test.

My adb environment var and Android devices are all set down (seen in attach screenshots).

However when I run the python or java test code, the appium server always tells me that my adb.exe and build tools folder could not be found. I spent aloooooooooot of time on finding the solution on google but nothing works.

[adb devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQT9l.jpg)

[could not find adb.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yVw9.jpg)

[could not find build-tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0useo.jpg)

[sdk root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KTPs.jpg)

[adb.exe root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dN7y.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

From the screenshot you attached it seems like you have updated multiple paths separated by semi colon all under `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable.

Set the environment variables properly for `ANDROID_HOME` and `Path` as described below,

- `ANDROID_HOME`: SDK root path only
- `PATH`: %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
- `PATH`: %ANDROID_HOME%\tools

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to restart your appium server after the above changes are made.